# Multidimensional Array Looping in cellForRowAtIndexPath Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, for-in-loop

I have a multidimensional array that I want to display the values of  onto one UILabel in each respective cell.

My arrays look like this:

`var arrayExample = [["beverages", "food", "suppliers"]["other stuff, "medicine"]]`

I'm looping through these values in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in order for it to display on different cells (on a UILabel) the appropriate values:

```
if let onTheLabel: AnyObject = arrayOfContactsFound as? AnyObject {

                for var i = 0; i < objects!.count; i++ {


                    cell?.contactsUserHas.text = "\(onTheLabel[indexPath.row][i])" as! String

                    print("arrayOfContactsFound Printing! \(onTheLabel)")

                }

            }
```

When printing to the console I get:

```
arrayOfContactsFound Printing! (
        (
        beverages,
        "supply chain",
        pharmacuticals
    )
)
```

But on my label I get "beverages". That's it. How can I get the other 2 values (or X amount if there are more or less than 3 values)?

My `for in loop` is obviously not doing the trick. Assuming I can optimize/fix that to display all the values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you're setting the text of your label multiple times. Each time you set it it doesn't accumulate, it completely replaces the current text with the new text. You'll want something like this:

```
    // Remove the cast and the loop in your code example, and replace with this
    let items = arrayOfContactsFound[indexPath.row]
    let itemsString = items.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    cell?.contactsUserHas.text = itemsString
```

Another thing to note is your cast doesn't quite make a lot of sense.

```
var arrayExample = [["beverages", "food", "suppliers"]["other stuff, "medicine"]]
```

So `arrayExample` is of type `[[String]]`. I'm assuming each cell in your table view represents one of the arrays of strings in your array. So each cell represents one `[String]`. So your `items` should be `arrayExample[indexPath.row]`. The cast to `AnyObject` doesn't make too much sense. If anything you'd be casting it to `[[AnyObject]]`, but there's no reason to because the compiler should already know it's `[[String]]`.

Comment: A bit confused... are these 3 different ways of doing it or 2 different ways? Also, my array is an `AnyObject` array. The last line you posted doesn't have the `joinWithSeparator(" ")` method. @andrewcarter

Comment: I tried all 3 ways. It doesn't work. It actually doesn't output anything just a `(` on the label. Can you give the full code in reference to what I posted? @Andrewcarter

Comment: I adjusted the text to simply be what your implementation should look like.

Comment: Yup, works now. Thanks for the explanation on the down casting as well. I changed it to a [[String]]. I was getting an error earlier when pulling the array from Parse and then trying to convert it so I set it to AnyObject. Should have just done the [[String]] from the beginning! Now it works smoothly. Thanks once again. @andrewcarter

Comment: was also wondering how I can extract individual values from the array? How to index it and put it on different labels. Very much appreciated.